# Bounce processing using oath-client with GSuite: Required parameter not passed: "refresh_token"

Tags: civimail, google, oauth, bounce-processing

Using CiviCRM 5.37.2.

I'm trying to use the oath-client extension to do OAuth authentication of a Google Workspace (GSuite) account for bounce processing. The credentials are created on the Google side of things, and when I set up the Mail Account in CiviCRM and assign it to bounce processing, it works; "Save and Test" responds positively. And if I then go to the Scheduled Jobs and immediately execute the Bounces Fetcher job, it completes successfully.

However, after a little while, it fails to run, with this error:

```
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message:
Finished execution of Bounces fetcher with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for [the email address used for bounce processing]
Error message:

Required parameter not passed: "refresh_token"
```

Is this a problem with the oauth-client extension, or have I mis-set a setting somewhere in CiviCRM?

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue with using google + civi oauth. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2184